# Filter LoadBalancer By VPC ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have two loadbalancers associated with two different VPC.

I am able to list all loadbalancers using AWS CLI.

Now I need to retrieve the name of the loadbalancer in a particular VPC. Is it can be done via AWS CLI ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is true that the ELB service provides no service side filtering of results.  However, you don't need to write a script to get what you want.  You can use the built-in jmespath querying capability of AWSCLI.

```
$ aws elb describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[?VPCId==`vpc-12345678`]|[].LoadBalancerName'
[
    "elb1", 
    "elb2"
]
$
```

Should return only a list of names of load balancers that are in `vpc-12345678`.